# Make required any one of two props in a functional component react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

For example I have a functional component like-

```
// my-component.tsx

interface Props {
  propA?: string;
  propB?: number;
}
const MyComponent = ({propA, propB}: Props) => {
  return <div>Hello world</div>
}
```

Now I am using the `MyComponent` to my application.

```
// index.tsx
const App = () => {
  return <MyComponent propA="Hello" />; // valid
  // or
  return <MyComponent propB={2} />; // valid
  // or
  return <MyComponent />; // should be invalid
}
```

Here all the three use cases are valid because the `propA` and `propB` both are optional. But I want something like I must have to pass any one of the `propA` or `propB`. Without any one of those props, the component will be invalid and code editor shows error.

In this case the first two return cases are valid but need the 3rd case would be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the type as
`type Props = { propA?: string } | { propB?: number }`